# How do I get one row for every Min or Max on every column of a dataframe in Pyspark efficiently?

Tags: performance, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to reduce a big dataset to rows having minimum and maximum values for each column. In other words, I would like, for every column of this dataset to get one row that has the minimum value on that column, as well as another that has the maximum value on the same column. I should mention that I do not know in advance what columns this dataset will have. Here's an example:

```
+----+----+----+     +----+----+----+
|Col1|Col2|Col3| ==> |Col1|Col2|Col3|
+----+----+----+     +----+----+----+
| F  | 99 | 17 |     | A  | 34 | 25 |
| M  | 32 | 20 |     | Z  | 51 | 49 |
| D  |  2 | 84 |     | D  |  2 | 84 |
| H  | 67 | 90 |     | F  | 99 | 17 |
| P  | 54 | 75 |     | C  | 18 |  9 |
| C  | 18 |  9 |     | H  | 67 | 90 |
| Z  | 51 | 49 |     +----+----+----+
| A  | 34 | 25 |
+----+----+----+
```

The first row is selected because A is the smallest value on Col1. The second because Z is the largest value on Col1. The third because 2 is the smallest on Col2, and so on. The code below seems to do the right thing (correct me if I'm wrong), but performance is sloooow. I start with getting a dataframe from a random .csv file:

```
input_file = (sqlContext.read
    .format("csv")
    .options(header="true", inferSchema="true", delimiter=";", charset="UTF-8")
    .load("/FileStore/tables/random.csv")
)
```

Then I create two other dataframes that each have one row with the min and respectively, max values of each column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, min, max

min_values = input_file.select(
    *[min(col(col_name)).name(col_name) for col_name in input_file.columns]
)

max_values = input_file.select(
    *[max(col(col_name)).name(col_name) for col_name in input_file.columns]
)
```

Finally, I repeatedly join the original input file to these two dataframes holding minimum and maximum values, using every column in turn, and do a union between all the results.

```
min_max_rows = (
  input_file
    .join(min_values, input_file[input_file.columns[0]] == min_values[input_file.columns[0]])
    .select(input_file["*"]).limit(1)
    .union(
      input_file
        .join(max_values, input_file[input_file.columns[0]] == max_values[input_file.columns[0]])
        .select(input_file["*"]).limit(1)
    )
)

for c in input_file.columns[1:]:
  min_max_rows = min_max_rows.union(
    input_file
      .join(min_values, input_file[c] == min_values[c])
      .select(input_file["*"]).limit(1)
      .union(
        input_file
          .join(max_values, input_file[c] == max_values[c])
          .select(input_file["*"]).limit(1)
      )
  )

min_max_rows.dropDuplicates()
```

For my test dataset of 500k rows, 40 columns, doing all this takes about 7-8 minutes on a standard Databricks cluster. I'm supposed to sift through more than 20 times this amount of data regularly. Is there any way to optimize this code? I'm quite afraid I've taken the naive approach to it, since I'm quite new to Spark.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting thing, will look tonight - have an idea but not sure if it will matter in performance.

Comment: Some goodies for u

Comment: I might have a small logic error, will re-check tonight

Comment: I think I overlooked one thing, will get back.

Comment: Actually, I overlooked 2 things. The notion that you can have any sorts of columns is a little hard to solve. The problem is that the same value can appear in different columns and that is what I am looking at. Again, interesting problem. Should be ready later on.

Comment: Fixed, see correct solution, not addressing all your requests, some work for you to do, but a non-procedural approach that allows scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not seem to be a popular question, but interesting (for me). And a lot of work for 15 pts. In fact I got it wrong first time round.

Here is a scaleable solution that you can partition accordingly to increase throughput.

> Hard to explain, manipulation of the data and transposing the data is
>   the key issue here - and some lateral thinking.

I did not focus on variable columns all sorts of data types. That needs to be solved by yourself, can be done but some if else logic required to check if alpha or double or numeric. Mixing data types and applying to stuff gets problematic, but can be solved. I gave a notion of num_string, but did not complete that.

I have focused on the scalability issue and approach, with less procedural logic.  Smaller sample size with all numbers, but correct as now as far as I can see. General principle is there.

Try it. Success.

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def reshape(df, by):
    cols, dtypes = zip(*((c, t) for (c, t) in df.dtypes if c not in by))
    kvs = explode(array([
      struct(lit(c).alias("key"), col(c).alias("val")) for c in cols
    ])).alias("kvs")

return df.select(by + [kvs]).select(by + ["kvs.key", "kvs.val"])

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(
[(4, 15, 3), (200, 100, 25), (7, 16, 4)], ("c1", "c2", "c3"))
df1 = df1.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())                                   
df1.cache  
df1.show()

df2 = reshape(df1, ["rowId"])
df2.show()

# In case you have other types like characters in the other column - not focusing on that aspect
df3 = df2.withColumn("num_string", format_string("%09d", col("val")))

# Avoid column name issues.
df3 = df3.withColumn("key1", col("key"))
df3.show()

df3 = df3.groupby('key1').agg(min(col("val")).alias("min_val"), max(col("val")).alias("max_val"))
df3.show()

df4 = df3.join(df2, df3.key1 == df2.key)
new_column_condition = expr(
    """IF(val = min_val, -1, IF(val = max_val, 1, 0))"""
)
df4 = df4.withColumn("col_class", new_column_condition)
df4.show()

df5 = df4.filter(  '(min_val = val or max_val = val) and col_class <> 0'  ) 
df5.show()

df6 = df5.join(df1, df5.rowId == df1.rowId)
df6.show()

df6.select([c for c in df6.columns if c in ['c1','c2', 'c3']]).distinct().show()  

Returns:

+---+---+---+
| c1| c2| c3|
+---+---+---+
|  4| 15|  3|
|200|100| 25|
+---+---+---+
```

> Data wrangling the clue here.

Comment: Thank you! Struggled a bit to understand it, but it does work better

Comment: Data Wrangling, it is also hard for me to explain, sort of experience.